# Updating a grails template using AJAX and JSON

Tags: ajax, templates, grails

in my view I have

`<g:render template="/common/notifications" model="[userNotifications:userNotifications]" />`

in javascript I have an ajax call to return a JSON object of `Notification`s

The controller method being called is as follows:

```
def getNotifications()
{
    def userNotifications = Notification.findAllByUser(UserUtils.getCurrentUser())      

    render userNotifications as JSON
}
```

but I dont have a clue how to get the response data to provide the template with the model

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of rendering the objects, render the template. Have your ajax expect HTML in return:

```
render(template: '/common/notifications', model: [userNotifications: userNotifications])
```

Comment: ah right, so I assume its a matter of creating a `div`, say with `id` of `notificationContainer` then in the success callback in javascript call `$('#notificationContainer').html(data)` ? It seems to work, is that the right way to do it?  Thanks for your help :)